# node_delete doesn't work!

Tags: 7, nodes

I am calling `node_delete($nid)` from inside a function callback that is called when the DELETE button is pressed, but the node is not deleted.  There is no error - it just doesn't work!  What can be going wrong?

In `bhl_form_alter()` I put:

```
$form['actions']['delete']['#submit']['0'] = 'delete_mem';
```

Then `delete_mem($node)` calls `node_delete($node->nid)`.

I have also tried to figure out a way to use the default callback `hook_node_delete()`, but if I put a redirect there with `drupal_goto()`, the redirect happens, but the node again does not get deleted. `drupal_form_redirect()` doesn't work in this function because `$form_state` is not passed.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's not possible to understand why your code doesn't work.

Comment: hook_node_delete() is a hook function you add to your module if you want to respond to the deletion of nodes. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7

Comment: It would also help to see the complete code of bhl_form_alter(), which is called for every form build from Drupal. Showing a single line doesn't help to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The first mistake in the code is how the additional submission handler is added. You should add it with the following code:

```
$form['actions']['delete']['#submit'][] = 'delete_mem';
```

If you want to be sure that submission handler is executed first, you should use the following code:

```
array_unshift($form['actions']['delete']['#submit'], 'delete_mem');
```

The second error is the argument declared for the form submission handler that, as shown in this [documentation page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7), should be:

```
function delete_mem($form, &$form_state) {}
```

As consequence of this, if you defined your function as `function delete_mem($node)` and you call `node_delete($node->nid)` from that function, `node_delete()` doesn't work because what you are calling `$node` is really a form array, which doesn't contain the `nid` property; what you are passing to `node_delete()` is `NULL`, and the function doesn't delete any node. Eventually, `NULL` could be converted to `0`, but there aren't nodes using `0` as node ID, and the function will not find any node to delete.
If you are using a Drupal development snapshot, you would get a warning about accessing a property of something that is not an object.

Supposing that you are altering the node edit form, the submission handler you are writing has access to the node object through `$form_state['node']`; the node ID can then retrieved with `$form_state['node']->nid`.

You can check the code executed from the [default submission handler](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_delete_submit/7) added from the Node module to the "Delete" button, which is the following one.

```
function node_form_delete_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $destination = array();
  if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
    $destination = drupal_get_destination();
    unset($_GET['destination']);
  }
  $node = $form['#node'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('node/' . $node->nid . '/delete', array('query' => $destination));
}
```

It uses `$form['#node']` to get the node object, and `$node->nid` to get its node ID. Consider the note added in [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) about `$form['#node']`.

```
  // @todo D8: Remove. Modules should access the node using $form_state['node'].
  $form['#node'] = $node;
```

This means that using `$form['#node']` would not working anymore on Drupal 8 (or any future version), while `$form_state['node']` would still work for Drupal 8 and any future Drupal version.

In this case, your submission handler doesn't need to call `node_delete()` as the function is already called from the submission handler added from the Node module to the "Delete" button. If you really need to delete information about a node that is being delete from a database table that your module uses, then you should implement [hook_node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7).

> I have also tried to figure out a way to use the default callback `hook_node_delete()`

`hook_node_delete()` is a hook that needs to be implemented. If your module is bhl.module, the function that needs to be written has the following signature:

```
function bhl_node_delete($node)
```

That hook is implemented when you need to delete data saved from your module in its own database table, where you save some custom data and the node ID. It is not required to delete a node, which a task already done from [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7), which contains the following code.

```
try {
  foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    // Call the node-specific callback (if any):
    node_invoke($node, 'delete');
    module_invoke_all('node_delete', $node);
    module_invoke_all('entity_delete', $node, 'node');
    field_attach_delete('node', $node);

    // Remove this node from the search index if needed.
    // This code is implemented in node module rather than in search module,
    // because node module is implementing search module's API, not the other
    // way around.
    if (module_exists('search')) {
      search_reindex($nid, 'node');
    }
  }

  // Delete after calling hooks so that they can query node tables as needed.
  db_delete('node')
    ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
    ->execute();
  db_delete('node_revision')
    ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
    ->execute();
  db_delete('history')
    ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
    ->execute();
  db_delete('node_access')
   ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
   ->execute();
}
```

Inside the implementation of [hook_node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7), you don't call [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete/7), or you cause an infinite loop. In fact, `node_delete()` calls [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7), which then invokes any implementation of `hook_node_delete()`, including yours that would call `node_delete()`, that would call `node_delete_multiple()`, which again would invoke any `hook_node_delete()` implementation, including yours.

As general suggestion, the functions defined from a module should always be prefixed from the short module name. In your case, if the hook function is `bhl_form_alter()`, the submission handler should be `bhl_delete_mem()`.

Comment: I'm sorry to say you are incorrect. The signature for hook_node_delete is `hook_node_delete($node)`.  This is the problem.  There is no access to $form or $form_state.  Doc for this is here:  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7

Comment: this seems to be the same for the additional submission handler.  Any thought on why node_delete does not work inside of the submission handler?

Comment: The problem is that you are not implementing `hook_node_delete()`, but you are adding a form submission handler, for which the arguments are `$form` and `$form_state`. A form submission handler, which is what you are using, and `hook_node_delete()` are two unrelated, and completely different, things.

Comment: yes, your right.  the problem I am having is that if I use a submission handler node_delete doesn't delete the node.  Here is the code: function bhl_delete_mem($form, &$form_state){
 node_delete($form['nid']['#value']);
 drupal_goto('memorabilia');
}

Comment: and if I use bhl_node_delete, I can't figure out how to redirect after the delete.  I tried drupal_goto and drupal_redirect_form.  Both redirect but don't delete the node!?  Thanks!

Comment: Form submission handlers are not supposed to redirect a form with `drupal_goto()`, but they should use `$form_state['redirect']`. `hook_node_delete()` is not supposed to redirect the users, as it can be called even when a form is not involved, such as during cron tasks.

Comment: ok, but any idea why node_delete is not deleting the node in the submission handler?  Thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2393/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-kiamlaluno)

Comment: Sorry to belabor the point, but I was in fact passing node_delete($form['nid']['#value']);  I used watchdog to insure that the proper node value was being passed.